# I am getting this error-"Uncaught TypeError: treePointWMSSource.getGetFeatureInfoUrl is not a function"

Tags: javascript, html, css, openlayers

In my javascript program I am getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: treePointWMSSource.getGetFeatureInfoUrl is not a function"
at this point-"// Add a single-click event listener to the map for feature information retrieval (as in your code)

```
map.on('singleclick', function (event) {
  var clickedCoordinate = event.coordinate;
  // Get the GetFeatureInfo URL for the clicked coordinate and resolution
  **var url = treePointWMSSource.getGetFeatureInfoUrl(**
    clickedCoordinate,
    view.getResolution(),
    view.getProjection(),
    { 'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json' }
  );"
```

How to remove it?

Comment: What version of OpenLayers are you using?  https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/main/changelog/upgrade-notes.md#renaming-of-getgetfeatureinfourl-to-getfeatureinfourl  Use getGetFeatureInfoUrl before version 6, getFeatureInfoUrl  with version 6 and later.

Comment: Ensure treePointWMSSource is an Instance of ol.source.ImageWMS or ol.source.TileWMS:
Only instances of ol.source.ImageWMS or ol.source.TileWMS in OpenLayers have the method getGetFeatureInfoUrl.